# .ppk derived from .pem key works but .pem don't in MobaXterm or file transfer programs

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, putty, ssh-keys, pem

I have an ec2 instance and it .pem key file, which I want to use for transfer files from my local machine to the server

I tried to connect the instance by using:

- mobaXterm with .pem file (before `chmod 400 abc.pem`) -- Error: `Server refused our key / No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`
- Putty with .ppk derived from the .pem file -- success
- winSCP with both keys -- Error
- `ssh -l user -i abc.pem user@ip` -- sometimes works*

Apparently I messed up the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, and the .PEM key is not allowed to connect the instance.

At this point the authorized_keys file have one row like this: `ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza....`

Then I did `chmod 400 abc.pem` and tried the followings:

I tried:

- from local machine `ssh -l ubuntu -i abc.pem ubuntu@ip`
- Mobaxterm with chmod-ed pem key
- winscp with chmod-ed pem and ppk key
- Copy the pem key at the .ssh/ folder in the server and then `ssh-add ~/keyfile.pem`

  - First answer:    `@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Permissions 0644 for 'cola-aws-ohio-key.pem' are too open. It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will be ignored.`
  - Second try after `chmod 400`: `Identity added: cola-aws-ohio-key.pem (cola-aws-ohio-key.pem)`
  - `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` looks same as before
  - Reboot instance
  - Try reconnecting again from mobaXterm: Fail
- Launch a new instance and use the chmod-ed pem key: fail

Any ideas on how to solve this? It is weird that ppk key (derived from pem file) works but the original pem key doesn't.

Comment: `ssh -l root -i abc.pem ubuntu@ip`, you're specifying both `root` and `ubuntu` for the uesrname.  I _think_ ssh will prefer the first username, so you're using `root`, which is probably not the correct choice.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks, Anon. I was able to connect using ssh, but I want to connect using Moba or other file manager software to transfer files. Let me modify the question, and thanks again for your input --- yes, I need ´-l user´ and ´user@ip´

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved the problem after many workarounds:

1. Updated MobaXterm -- I know
2. Be sure about a.pem permissions. I'm on Windows with WSL too.
   The file's permission is `-rwxrwxrwx` but should be `-r--------` (`-r--r--r--` also works for me)

I tried chmod  400 a.pem, and it only works if the file is located on Ubuntu/Linux internal folder (`~`), not on the Windows shared folder (`/mnt/c/...`). However, when I tried copy the file from Ubuntu/Linux internal folder to Windows (where MobaXterm can use it), the permission changed back to `-rwxrwxrwx`

I also tried :

- zip and tar the key on Ubuntu, and uncompress on Windows: Fail
- Upload to Github from Ubuntu and download in Windows: Fail
- Cheange manually the permission on Windows: Fail

So I changed the permissions in Windows using PowerShell as admin, with the following [code](https://gist.github.com/jaskiratr/cfacb332bfdff2f63f535db7efb6df93):

```
cd C:\mydir
icacls.exe a.pem /reset
icacls.exe a.pem /grant:r "$($env:username):(r)"
icacls.exe a.pem /inheritance:r
```

Apparently the combination of updating MobaXterm and being sure about file permissions were the way this works

Answer (score -1):

amazon linux 2023 and ubuntu 22 user updated version of openssl,
you need to get a updated key
ssh-keygen -o -a 100 -t ed25519